# Dual boot system no longer shows ubuntu as option after startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows-10

I have a lenovo thinkpad running windows 10 pro and ubuntu 20.04. I installed ubuntu a few months ago, and have not had a problem with running it on my laptop - the grub menu automatically popped up when I restarted my laptop every time. However, recently, the grub menu stopped appearing and my laptop automatically booted into windows 10. I have gone into the BIOS startup menu - my computer is in UEFI boot mode, with windows boot options as the first priority, but ubuntu no longer appears as an option. I have tried changing boot priority to every other option, but none of them restart my laptop into ubuntu, they all redirect back to the windows system. When I restart my laptop using the F-12 key, it shows windows as the only option for restart. How can I get back into my ubuntu operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like another "helpful" Windows update has resulted in wasting people's time.

As you're running Windows 10, you'll want to run "Command Prompt" as administrator and enter this command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

This will change the boot manager's path back to Grub, so long as the update to Windows did not also make changes to any partitions.

After making the change, reboot and you should see the option to choose your operating system again.

Comment: Thank you! I tried running this command, and it says that "operation was successful" but when I reboot, it still does not show me the menu to choose an operating system... do you have any other suggestions of what it could be? I am looking at my partitions, and it shows that all of them are 100% free, and I have multiple things installed in my ubuntu, so it should not be free...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include screenshots of your partition data? Any additional details can help point towards a solution.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, but I actually figured it out! just had to change my boot mode to legacy support - thanks so much anyways!